# How to use premium full archive search

Tags: python, twitter

I want to get 1000 tweets (without retweets) for the period 07/08/2006 00:00 to 07/08/2006 23:59 using the premium full archive. The api returns maximum 500 tweets per request. How can I get 1000 tweets without running my code two times? Also, how can I export the tweets in a csv format by including all the keys?

I am new in python. I tried to get the tweets but as I said in the summary description I'm getting 500 tweets (including rtweets). Also, when i save the tweets in the csv, every even row is empty.
for example:

```
|---------- |------|------|----|
|created_at |id_str|source|user|
|---------- |------|------  |----|
|2008|949483|www.none.com|John|
|----------|------|------|----|
|empty |empty |empty|empty|
|----------|------|------|----|
|2009|74332|www.non2.com|Marc|
|----------|------|------|----|
|empty |empty |empty|empty|
```

My questions are:
How can I get 1000 tweets (excluding rtweets) without getting duplicated tweets and running the code 1 time? and How can I save all the keys of the outputs in a csv without having empty even rows?

```py
    from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
import csv

SEARCH_TERM = '@nOne'
PRODUCT = 'fullarchive'
LABEL = 'dev-environment'

api = TwitterAPI("consumer_key", 
             "consumer_secret", 
             "access_token_key", 
             "access_token_secret")

r = api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL), 
            {'query':SEARCH_TERM, 
            'fromDate':'200608070000',
            'toDate':'200608072359',
             "maxResults":500
            })

csvFile = open('data.csv', 'w',encoding='UTF-8')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for item in r:
    csvWriter.writerow([item['created_at'],
                    item["id_str"],
                    item["source"],                    
                    item['user']['screen_name'],
                    item["user"]["location"],
                    item["geo"],
                    item["coordinates"], 
                    item['text'] if 'text' in item else item])
```

I expect to get a dataframe with 1000 unique tweets (excluding retweets) by running the code once in a csv format?

Thanks

Comment: If the API returns 500 results per request, then obviously you'll have to call it twice.

Comment: Is 500 a hard limit enforced by the API?  I see you're passing `"maxResults":500` as part of the API request; perhaps you're imposing that limit on yourself?

Comment: Yes it is. The issue is when I call it the second time I want to get next 500 tweets

Comment: It looks like the API response includes a `next` element, which you can use in your second request to ask it to continue from the 501st item instead of starting a fresh search.  See https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search#Pagination

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) package, you should take advantage of the `TwitterPager` class which uses the `next` element in the returned JSON to get the next page of tweets. Look at this [simple example](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/page_tweets.py) to understand the usage.

In your case, you would simply replace this:

```
r = api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL), 
        {'query':SEARCH_TERM, 
        'fromDate':'200608070000',
        'toDate':'200608072359',
        "maxResults":500
        })
```

...with this:

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterPager

r = TwitterPager(api, 'tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL),
        {'query':SEARCH_TERM, 
        'fromDate':'200608070000',
        'toDate':'200608072359',
        "maxResults":500
        }).get_iterator()
```

By default, `TwitterPager` waits 5 seconds between requests. In the Sandbox environment you should be able to reduce this to 2 seconds without exceeding the rate limit. To change the wait to 2 seconds you would call `get_iterator` with a parameter, like this:

```
get_iterator(wait=2)
```